# Azure DevOps pass object type parameters to a template and access it inside the template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to pass a parameter of type `object` to an Azure DevOps template. And I am trying to access that passed parameter inside a bash script (`inlineScript`). Please find what I am doing below:

`deploy.yaml`

```
. . .
- template: build/deploy.helm@templates
  parameters:
    helmfile_envs:
      - IMAGE_TAG: test
      - SOME_VALUE: some-value
```

`build/deploy.helm@templates`

```
parameters:
- name: helmfile_envs
  type: object

. . . 

     - task: AzureCLI@1
       . . .
       inputs:
         . . . 
         scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
         inlineScript: |
           ${{ each env in parameters.helmfile_envs }} :
             echo $env
```

but I am getting the following error:

> The directive 'each' is not allowed in this context. Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression.

Is there a way to pass this `object` type parameter `helmfile_envs` and access it within an `inlineScript`?

Could someone please help me?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The use of `each` in an inlineScript is not supported. We can use `each` in steps like the following yaml:

```
#Template.yml

parameters:
- name: helmfile_envs
  type: object

steps:
- ${{ each helmfile_env in parameters.helmfile_envs }}:
  
  - task: AzureCLI@2    
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'service connection name'
      scriptType: 'batch'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        echo ${{ helmfile_env.IMAGE_TAG }}
        echo ${{ helmfile_env.SOME_VALUE}}
    displayName: 'ENV name ${{ helmfile_env.ENV_name }}'
```

The deploy yaml:

```
#Deploy.yml

parameters:
- name: helmfile_envs
  type: object
  default:
    - ENV_name: object1
      IMAGE_TAG: test1
      SOME_VALUE: some-value1
    - ENV_name: object2
      IMAGE_TAG: test2
      SOME_VALUE: some-value2

trigger: none
pool: 
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- template: Template.yml
  parameters:
    helmfile_envs: ${{parameters.helmfile_envs}}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one question, is it possible to pass `helmfile_envs` without `default`? How can I specify these values in the template step other than in the `parameters` section?

Comment: And also, is it possible to concatenate each `helmfile_env` so I can build up a final command like `helmfile -e dev --state-values-set ${{ helmfile_env.IMAGE_TAG }}=${{ helmfile_env.IMAGE_TAG }} --state-values-set ${{ helmfile_env.SOME_VALUE}}=${{ helmfile_env.SOME_VALUE}} --state-values-set . . .`

Comment: Hi, if you pass `helmfile_envs` without `default`, you will need to input the value manually when you run the pipeline.  And I didn't find the way to specify these values in the template step other than in the parameters section in my test.      I can successfully `echo ${{ helmfile_env.IMAGE_TAG }}`, so I believe you can build up a final command as you mentioned.